# FOSUserBundle Login do nothing

Tags: forms, security, symfony

I got Symfony2 2.7.3 running on my localhost and FOSUserBundle ~2.0@dev

When I submit the login form, the view resets, without lastUsername, errors or something like this. Just the form.

I saw the logs of symfony and php and it don't show some info about that.

This is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:         ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SWITCH_ROLES:  ROLE_SWITCH_ROLES

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                use_referer:  true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                success_handler: authentication_handler
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000
                path:     /
                domain:   "%domain%"
                name:     "REMEMEMBERME"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My config.yml configuration to fos_user:

```
# FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AcmeBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
            template:   UserBundle:Email:registration.email.html.twig
        form:
            type:               fos_user_registration
            name:               fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
    resetting:
        email:
            template: UserBundle:Email:resetting.email.html.twig
    from_email:
        address:        %mailer_user%
        sender_name:    Lucas
    profile:
        form:
            type: lucas_user_profile
```

Comment: Did you add a routes as well?

Comment: Yes, it was working well until 2 or 3 days :/